# deployer.org how to change releases' folder's name

Tags: php-deployer

After I deploy by command to my server:

```
bin/dep deploy
```

In "`releases`" folder I have folders named liked `1`, `2`, `3`, ...

How can I change it to timestamp, so after deploy command I'll get something like this `20160425120500` instead of `1`

```
bin/dep --version
Deployer 6.0.5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I`m not checked solution, but you can try this

```
set('release_name', function () {
    return (string) run('date +"%s"');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help^^

Comment: @MonTea, oh! Sure, it's just typo. Here one semicolon

Comment: Alternative `date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`